# Android: convert databse file to .csv file then email it

Tags: android, database, csv

i have a database created under data/data/(my package name)/databases/(my db) what i want to achieve now is store the databse in a .csv file then email it is it even possible in android

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Please use Google.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
Loop through your cursor and generate a csv file.
Then, send an email intent.

If you have an other question, please ask it explicity.

Comment: I'm not able to create csv in my android by using implementation files('libs/opencsv-4.1.jar') , Can you please tell me how to create csv file in android and attached that file in email. i already put the code but i'm not getting the location of csv. Pleae help me

Comment: Please ask explicity your issue. We cannot do the whole project for you

Comment: My Code :
 String csv = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
I'm not able to get Location of csv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android