# Android - Creating Text Files

Tags: java, android, text

I need help to make a very simple app for android that just creates text files on the click of a button. Can anyone help me with the coding? I already made the activity_main.xml set out already, but now I want to know how I can get a button to create a .txt or a .doc file which users can write in! (Something like a notepad)

Comment: google it once .. m sure u will find answer if any more query u can add comments

Comment: http://edisontus.blogspot.sg/2013/01/simple-notepad-for-android.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public void addTextToFile(String text) {
        File logFile = new File("sdcard/" + "MyFile.txt");
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            try {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
            buf.append(text);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```