# How to create and write data a text file in android programatically?

Tags: android

I am creating a sample application in my android phone to create a new text file and write some data on to that text file.

Comment: which type of data?

Comment: Same like java. Just you have to mention where to keep that file. e.g. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/text/"

Comment: Normal string data

Comment: What exactly does Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  do

Answer (score 9):

Use these code you can write a text file in SDCard along with you need to set permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

for device having os >= LOLIPOP you need to ask permissions runtime,
this is the code :

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's, it's working fine

Comment: copy cat https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152217/5289704