# Writing to file using getFilesDir() giving 'Read-only file system' error (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, internal-storage, transformer-model

I want to write to my application's internal file directory but I am getting the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: com.android.internal.os.AndroidPrintStream@47a0990 (Read-only file system)`

So it says it is 'read-only' storage. I am using `getFilesDir()` to retrieve the path and  I have seen lots of examples online of people using this to write to the internal storage. Why am I seeing this error?

My code is below:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

// Root element
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("license");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

// Write content to XML file.
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/license.xml"));
System.out.println("Saving to: " + context.getFilesDir().getPath());
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The exception is thrown at the final line of my code.

I have the following permissions in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note, I don't want to write to external storage as this file should not be visible to users.

I can write to the same directory using a `FileOutputStream` without it throwing any exception...so why does the `Transformer` encounter this read-only issue?

Comment: your file in device memory or sd card?

Comment: It should be in device memory, in /data/user/0/[my app]/files

Comment: @petehallw what device are you using?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I'm using a Moto G4 phone with Android 7.0.

Comment: @petehallw: Did you try Shared Preferences option

Comment: @petehallw have you tried to create a file in the other way?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Which other way do you mean?

Comment: @petehallw create a simple file using one the those ways: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8152125/1979882

Comment: @Vyacheslav Yes I'm able to create a file using `FileOutputStream` but not with the stream in my `Transformer` (I added this to my question recently).

Comment: @petehallw , i would suggest to create an empty file and then use transformer

Comment: I created a file using `OutputStreamWriter` and verified this by reading it back in and printing it's contents. I then tried to write to that file using the method in my question, and get the same read-only error.

Answer (score 1):

`getFilesDir()` is `/data/data/com.example.apk/files`

You need not to use those permissions.

It says `filenotfound`. Try to create it first.

Nevertheless, it's strange

Comment: ah... yes. Know i got the real case thanks @Vyacheslav

Comment: @gumuruh i'm really happy, this answer helped in 5 years! =)