# Write text file in the device's storage

Tags: android

how to write a text file in a public storage that it was visible for other apps. i.e. file manager. 
what is wrong with my code.

```
String filename = "kontaktebi123.vcf";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        PrintWriter osw = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        ArrayList<String> nomrebi = numberGenerator(view);
        osw.printf("blablabla")
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Refer this link...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the file in public directory like `Document`, `Download` or others.

```
String fileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "kontaktebi123.vcf";

File file = new File(fileDir + "/" + fileName);
```

Now write in the file and it will be visible to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
FileOutputStream fileOutStream =  openFileOutput(fileName.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutStream);
outputWriter.write("write your text here");
outputWriter.close();
Toast.maketext(context,"File Saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```