# How to create a text file inside the directory that I have created (Android External Storage)

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I want to create a `text file` inside the `folder` that I have created using code. I have created the `RegUp`. Now I need to create a `text file` inside the `RegUp` folder.

**Code I used to create the folder:**

```
if(isExternalStorageWritable())
{
      String albumName = "RegUP";
      String fileName = "file.txt";

      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), albumName);

      if (!file.mkdirs())
      {
            Log.e("msg", "Directory not created");
      }
      else
      {
            Log.e("msg", "Directory created");

      }
}
```

Comment: what is problem with above code?

Comment: @KaranMer no problem. This is the code used to make the folder named `RegUP`. I just provided the code to show how I created the folder.

Comment: Have you gone through this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android

Comment: @MiniChip No I didn't. Just checked that post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

like below:

```
if(isExternalStorageWritable())
{
  String albumName = "RegUP";
  String fileName = "file.txt";

  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), albumName);

  if (!file.mkdirs())
  {
        Log.e("msg", "Directory not created");
  }
  else
  {
        File new_File=new File(file.getPath()+"/"+fileName);//you can now write to this file
        Log.e("msg", "Directory created");

  }


 }
```