# /storage/emulated/0/Notes/ (No such file or directory)?

Tags: java, android, text-files

I tried this link:

[How to create text file and insert data to that file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android)

But, it says "No such file or directory". Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must first ask runtime permission to write external directory. Just declaring permission in manifest isn't enough. Starting from android 6 you must ask runtime permission.

Comment: Thanks for this comments. I already added this to the manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and uses latest version

Comment: Do you ask runtime permission?

Comment: @Bek what do you mean by asking runtime permission?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: You are on Q i think. You should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Bek Thanks bro. Asking runtime permission is the key.

Answer (score 0):

---- Updated answer----

I think you can't create a directory inside the internal storage of the device. Except you've a root access for the app. You can only create the directory inside your app private folder within the following path String `path = getFilesDir().`

you can use like this below -

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydirectory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myAwesomeFile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

`getDir(StringName, int mode)` method to create or access directories in internal storage.

/storage/emulated/0/Notes/ will always return `No such file or directory` except device is rooted and `dir.mkDirs()` will always return false for this path.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is it ok to use latest version of android?

Comment: Welcome brother. If that helps you kindly mark the answer as accepted and upvote so that it will help others too. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pakz yeh its completely ok to use latest stable version.

Comment: I tried your codes but same output. I cannot create folder and textfile.

Comment: @Pakz I got your problem--- Please see my updated answer.

Comment: What do you consider to be the last Android version?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Notes/ will always return No such file or directory` No. It is always ok. Except for Android Q.

Comment: `think you can't create a directory inside the internal storage of the device` Even under Android Q one can using getExternalFilesDir().