# Creating a Text File in Android results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, text, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on an app that gets data over BLE and saves it in a text file.

The problem now is that I'm not able to create a text file with my app.

I've already tried the answers from this thread: [How to create text file and insert data to that file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android)
So please don't mark it as duplicated, cause the answers provided there won't work for me..

The corresponding code is:

```
try {
        System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        File root =new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "BLE_Crawler");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();

        }
        File file = new File(root, fileName +".txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {

                file.createNewFile();

        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer.append("test");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the error I get is:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/BLE_Crawler/test.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It seems that I don't have the rights to make a new folder cause the "mkdirs()" line doesn't work. But I don't know how to fix this problem.

Oh and I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.

I'm using SDKVersion 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to your manifest in `<application>` tag?
Also, don't forget that from Android 6.0 you need to request permissions even if you write them in your Manifest.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String[] permissions = new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permissions[i]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(permissions,
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Grogak no problem. I'd recommend reading https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases as this should be a temporary solution.